# Reduce spacing in bibliography using biblatex

Tags: spacing, biblatex

How can you control (in my case reduce) the spacing of the bibliography in biblatex? I used to use

```
\begin{spacing}{0.9}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{refs}
\end{spacing}
```

and

`\setlength{\bibsep}{0.0pt}`.  But how do you do the equivalent in biblatex?

EDIT: I should maybe have mentioned I am using

```
\begin{refsection}

\printbibliography[heading=subbibliography]

\end{refsection}

[..]


\begin{refsection}
```

to get multiple bibliographies and I would like to be able to control the spacing per bib.

```
\printbibliography[heading=subbibliography]

\end{refsection}
```

Comment: `\renewcommand{\bibfont}{\small}` will also make your bibliography take up less space.

Comment: Thanks.  Do you know exactly what font size that uses?

Comment: @Raphael that depends on what the font size of the main document is.

Comment: It is 11pt and Helvetica.  What is the rule?

Comment: @Raphael for 11pt text, `\small` is equivalent to about 10pt. See [this wikibook page](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Formatting#Sizing_text) for details

Answer (score 66, accepted):

`\bibitemsep` length between two    different entries, preset to `\itemsep`

`\bibnamesep` length between two    entries of different authors

`\bibinitsep` length between two    entries of authors with different first letter

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}% Part of the TeX distribution
\usepackage{setspace}
\onehalfspacing
\begin{document}
\blindtext

\singlespacing\blindtext

\nocite{*}

\begingroup
\setstretch{0.8}
\setlength\bibitemsep{0pt}
\printbibliography
\endgroup

\end{document}
```

[image]

By the way: I prefer to typeset a bibliography with `\RaggedRight` (from package `ragged2e`)

Comment: Thanks. How do I set that for just one of the bibs and how can I change the line spacing within a reference as \begin{spacing}{0.9} does.

Comment: for example: `\begingroup \setstretch{0.9} \setlength\<length>{0pt} \printbibliography \endgroup`

Comment: Thanks that seems to work. The only oddity is that \setstretch doesn't seem to do anything with very small values. For example \setstretch{0.1} looks much the same as \setstretch{0.9}.

Comment: what spacing do you have? single/onehalf/doublespacing? And are you using package setspace?

Comment: I am using the package setspace. I am trying to really squeeze the bibliography. I haven't set any spacing except for this \setstretch for the bibliography.

Comment: then use `\singlelinespacing` or do you want the bibliography set with less than one line spacing?

Comment: Yes I was hoping to be able to set the line spacing to be smaller than that.

Comment: @Raphael: see my edited answer with the image and an extremely small line space ...

Comment: That is lovely. However, if you reduce the 0.8 to 0.1 in setstretch for example. it doesn't make any difference for me.  I should say as an aside that the biblatex-examples.bib file I could find online has "@PREAMBLE{ "\RequireBiber[2]" } as the first line.

Comment: Sorry I didn't put your name in the comment above. My question was, why doesn't reducing setstretch from 0.8 to 0.1, say, make any difference?

Comment: @Raphael Because LaTeX will never make the lines collide. So once they are as close to each other as they can be, nothing's more gonna haappen.

Comment: @tohecz Thanks for this. The thing is that it looks like there is still space to save but maybe that is an illusion.

Comment: @Raphael That strongly depends on the font used and on its properties and how it's metric files are formed.

Answer (score 14):

```
\let\oldbibliography\thebibliography
\renewcommand{\thebibliography}[1]{\oldbibliography{#1}
\setlength{\itemsep}{0pt}} %Reducing spacing in the bibliography.
```

Comment: Worked perfectly! Thanks!!

Answer (score 6):

**Using BibTeX with `article` document class**

In the code below, the bibliography is typeset in the smaller font `\footnotesize`.  Article class sets by default the bibliography name as a `\section*`; it is replaced with `\subsubsection` to appear smaller.  The last trick is to rely on `\@openbib@code` as a hook to modify the list parameters that are used to display the references; in this case, the length between two references is reduced by setting `\itemsep` to 0pt.

```
\begingroup\footnotesize
\let\section\subsubsection
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\@openbib@code{\itemsep\z@}
\makeatother
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{<biblio file>}
\endgroup
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate a bit more on this solution so it becomes more helpful to others, not only the OP?

Comment: @TobiBS Done :)

Comment: Great, I upvoted for you!

Answer (score 5):

I had trouble using `\singlespace`. However I found the `.cls` file that my tex file referring to had defined an environment `singlespace`. So my way looks like this

```
\begin{singlespace}
\setlength\bibitemsep{10pt}   % length between two different entries
\printbibliography
\end{singlespace}
\addcontentsline{toc}{head}{REFERENCES}  % must be after \printbibliography or the page# is wrong
```