# How can I put more space between bibliography entries (biblatex)

Tags: spacing, biblatex

My bibliography (made with biblatex) has all items close to each other. I would like to introduce some space between them, e.g. half a line.

How can I do this?

Comment: Related question (the exact opposite indeed `;-)`): http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17360/reduce-spacing-in-bibliography-using-biblatex

Answer (score 101, accepted):

increase one of the lengths:

`\bibitemsep` length between two different entries, preset to `\itemsep`

`\bibnamesep` length between two entries of different authors

`\bibinitsep` length between two entries of authors with different first letter

For example, if you want to increase the `\bibitemsep` by 50%, you could use:

```
\setlength\bibitemsep{1.5\itemsep}
```

Comment: That won't work for packages where `\itemsep` is already zero. Better to use `\setlength\bibitemsep{0.5\baselineskip}` or something document-related.

Answer (score 22):

I've used the answer given by Herbert, but it didn't work for me. This could be probably due to the recent update of `biber` to v2.4 (March 2016).

Hereby, I propose an alternative that worked for me (i.e. introducing a space between the bibentries in the list):

```
\setlength\bibitemsep{\baselineskip}
```

You've to put this in the preamble right after `\usepackage{biblatex}`

Comment: Mhhh, a Biber update should have nothing to do with that. A `biblatex` update might just, but it is extremely unlikely I would say. The more likely explanation is that your documentclass sets `\itemsep` to a small value so that you can't tell `1.5\itemsep` from `\itemsep`. Without an example it is of course hard to say ...

Answer (score 2):

I've used the answer given by Herbert, but it didn't work for me too. It was because {1.5\itemsep} is the default size. `\setlength\bibitemsep{5\itemsep}` produced what I wanted to.

Comment: How is the different from the previous answer (except for the changes in the separation). Welcome to TEXSE.

Comment: Yes you are right. I'm not familiar with the interface. Thanks for welcoming me.

Comment: Indeed, I think this is more of a comment than an answer. Could you move it to the comment? In case, if you cannot do so (due to reputation), let me know, I will do it on behalf of you :)

Comment: The default size of `\bibitemsep` as defined in `biblatex.def` is `\setlength{\bibitemsep}{\itemsep}`, see [l. 292 of `biblatex.def`](https://github.com/plk/biblatex/blob/476a0dad3146012955b1f1441ffbc8f1d015ef35/tex/latex/biblatex/biblatex.def#L292). Some `biblatex` standard styles set `\bibitemep` to `0pt` (`authortitle`- and `authoryear`-based styles), but none sets it to `1.5\itemsep`. Maybe the `\itemsep` in your document is zero?

Answer (score 0):

A more efficient way is to use `setspace` package, which helps you set the **separation between lines** for `biblatex`.

Then you can use `\setlength{\bibitemsep}{10pt}` to set the item separation.

Here's a sample code:

```
\usepackage{biblatex}
\usepackage{setspace}

\linespread{2.0}
\setlength{\bibitemsep}{10pt}

\begin{spacing}{1.0}
\printbibliography[title={Works Cited}]
\end{spacing}
```

Comment: Well, `setspace` does something very different from `\bibitemsep`. `setspace` influences the separation between all lines. `\bibitemsep` influences the space between different entries. If a single entry has multiple lines, the two will behave differently.