# Line breaks between entries in Biblatex bibliography

Tags: spacing, biblatex

In my preamble, I set-up the bib as such:

```
\usepackage[style=authoryear,sorting=none, backend=biber,natbib]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{references.bib}
```

Where *references.bib* is formatted as such:

```
@inproceedings{inpreceed,
  title={},
  author={},
  journal={},
  year={}
}

@book{b,
  title={},
  author={},
  url={},
  year={},
  publisher={},
  location={}
}
```

And then printing my bibliography using the command:

```
\printbibliography
```

However, my bibliography lacks line breaks between entries, as shown below:
[image]

How can I make my bibliography more cleanly spaced?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question has been [asked](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/19105/134641), and [answered](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/19109/134641).

I provide that answer below, using a version from a [comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/19105/how-can-i-put-more-space-between-bibliography-entries-biblatex#comment770111_19109) on an answer to the original question:

```
\setlength\bibitemsep{0.5\baselineskip}
```

The above line should be placed within your preamble, after you have issued:

```
\usepackage[style=authoryear,sorting=none, backend=biber, natbib]{biblatex}
```