# Condense the space between bibliographic entries

Tags: spacing, bibliographies, lyx

In order to save space, I would like to condense the bibliography, specifically, reduce the amount of vertical space between entries. Currently, it seems there is double-space between consecutive entries.

I use the "article" layout in LyX.

Comment: If you switch to `natbib` then there is a `\bibsep` parameter that you can adjust.

Comment: Thank you! I added this to the Latex Preamble: "\setlength{\bibsep}{0.0pt}"

Comment: For people using bibtex in the article class and where yo''s and Hai Zhang's answers did not do the trick, have a look here: [https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17360/reduce-spacing-in-bibliography-using-biblatex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17360/reduce-spacing-in-bibliography-using-biblatex) This worked for me to reduce the space, whilst the other suggestions did not.

Answer (score 156, accepted):

As Andrew says, you can use `natbib` and then reset `\bibsep`:

```
\setlength{\bibsep}{0pt plus 0.3ex}
```

---

Without `natbib`, you can set `\parskip` and `\itemsep` to zero (they are responsible for the vertical space). It is advised to add some glue-stretch that can be used if necessary (this is what `plus 0.3ex` is for).

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}

% ADD THE FOLLOWING COUPLE LINES INTO YOUR PREAMBLE
\let\OLDthebibliography\thebibliography
\renewcommand\thebibliography[1]{
  \OLDthebibliography{#1}
  \setlength{\parskip}{0pt}
  \setlength{\itemsep}{0pt plus 0.3ex}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{thebibliography}{99}

\bibitem{a} \lipsum[1]

\bibitem{b} \lipsum[4]

\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This did not do anything for me. I added the lines you described, to my pre-amble. I'm trying to make the space between bibliography entries larger.

Answer (score 17):

For those who are using BibTeX but cannot use the `natbib` package (thus no `\bibsep`), and has tried varous `\renewcommand` on `\thebibliography` and `\itemsep` ([source](http://www.tex.ac.uk/FAQ-compactbib.html)), here is what I found that **actually works** in this scenario ([source](http://www-h.eng.cam.ac.uk/help/tpl/textprocessing/squeeze.html#Contentsandbibliography)):

```
\let\oldthebibliography\thebibliography
\let\endoldthebibliography\endthebibliography
\renewenvironment{thebibliography}[1]{
  \begin{oldthebibliography}{#1}
    \setlength{\itemsep}{0em}
    \setlength{\parskip}{0em}
}
{
  \end{oldthebibliography}
}
```

Comment: Isn't this exactly what yo' already did in the accepted answer?

Comment: @TeXnician No, this one is `renewenvironment` instead of `renewcommand`. Cann't remember if this made a difference though.

Comment: This makes no difference as an environment `x` defines a macro `\x` and a `\endx`. That's why your solution is even more complicated than the accepted one (since you also redefine `\endthebibliography`).