# space bibliography

Tags: spacing, bibtex, bibliographies

my bibliography looks like

```
Abowd, J.M., F. Kramarz, and D.N. Margolis. 1999. High-wage
Workers and High-wage Firms.Econometrica, 67(2): 251333.

Abowd, J.M., R.H. Creecy, and F. Kramarz. 2002. Computing
Person and Firm E¤ects Using Linked Longitudinal Employer-Employee
```

I would like to remove the space between the entries. how do i do that? To compile the bibliography I am using aea.bst downloadable from here http://www.aeaweb.org/templates/latex_templates.zip

Comment: Please, check whether the [Condense the space between bibliographic entries](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/93859/condense-the-space-between-bibliographic-entries) question helps you. If not, please edit your question to supply more information about the problem.