# Latex Bibliography Style

Tags: bibliographies

In my bibliography I want to remove the line break between references (now it is like the figure). The bibliography style I'm using is

```
\bibliographystyle{inc/splncsnat}
```

**Figure**

[image: Figure]

Any suggestion will be gracefully appreciate. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well I fix the problem, just add followings in my settings. make sure you have [natbib](http://www.stsci.edu/ftp/software/tex/aasmacros5/natbib.sty) style file. Thanks.

```
\usepackage{natbib}
\setlength{\bibsep}{0.0pt}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}

% ADD THE FOLLOWING COUPLE LINES INTO YOUR PREAMBLE
\let\OLDthebibliography\thebibliography
\renewcommand\thebibliography[1]{
  \OLDthebibliography{#1}
  \setlength{\parskip}{0pt}
  \setlength{\itemsep}{0pt plus 0.3ex}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{thebibliography}{99}

\bibitem{a} \lipsum[1]

\bibitem{b} \lipsum[4]

\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

as it is mentioned here: [Condense the space between bibliographic entries](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/95607/14992)

When you are using `biblatex`, you can use the following command:

```
\setlength\bibitemsep{0pt}

\printbibliography
```

as it is mentioned here: [Reduce spacing in bibliography using biblatex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/17363/14992)