# Add space between bibliography entries

Tags: spacing, apacite

can someone help me, I need my Bibliography looks like this:
[image]

But actually it look like

[image]

Need space between bibliography entries

I am using apacite and bitext

**My .tex file is this**

```
\documentclass[a4paper,oneside,11pt]{book}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx} % graficos
\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{phv} % Arial
\renewcommand{\sfdefault}{phv} % Arial
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{emptypage}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{array,multirow,graphicx}
\usepackage{anysize}
\usepackage{apacite}
\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}
\usepackage{emptypage}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{rotating}
\marginsize{3cm}{3cm}{1cm}{1cm}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}
\begin{document}
\include{Caratula/caratula}
\include{Aprobacion/aprobacion}
\include{Declaracion/declaracion}
\include{Dedicatoria/dedicatoria}
\include{Agradecimiento/agradecimiento}
\include{Indice/indice}
\include{Resumen/resumen}
\include{Abstract/abstract}
\include{Introduccion/introduccion}
\include{Capitulo1/capitulo1}
\include{Capitulo2/capitulo2}
\include{Capitulo3/capitulo3}
\include{Discucion/discucion}
\include{Concluciones/concluciones}
\include{Recomendaciones/recomendaciones}
\include{Bibliografia/bibliografia}
\include{Anexos/anexo1}
\end{document}
```

**and also use this**

```
\bibliographystyle{newapa}
\bibliography{biblio}
```

Comment: Welcome! Please provide a minimal example i.e. code which can be compiled to reproduce the issue. Right now, nobody but you can compile the code. This will include one or two sample `.bib` entries (or use a standard `.bib` file, if that works) and some text which cites them so that it produces problematic output when compiled.

Comment: The code you use shows that you don't use `biblatex`, but traditional BibTeX styles (namely `newapa.bst` with `apacite`), so I removed the `biblatex` tag. The `sharelatex` tag is also not relevant, so I removed it as well.

Comment: A very short search turned up http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/93859/35864 and https://wiki.math.cmu.edu/iki/wiki/tips/20140712-bibtex-spacing.html