# What is the easiest way to generate a compact bibliography?

Tags: biblatex, bibtex, best-practices

In a beamer presentation I want to use the `\nocite{*}` macro, so all entries in the `bib` file will be included, regardless whether I actually cited an entry or not. However, this yields a rather long list of references, since each entry yields many details.

What is the easiest way to generate a compact list of references. In particular, each entry should contain: Title, author(s) (probably at most 2), year.

It sounds like an easy task, but I couldn't find the right solution.

### Edit:

1. There is no particular reason for me not to use `biblatex`. It is an option.
2. Mostly, in the presentation's body there will be no citations. In case few would appear I'd like them to be formated with a number. Like: `On Foo Bar, see [1]`. Nevertheless, the list of reference *will* be long as I will use the `\notice{*}` macro.
3. In the list itself, I'd like to have: Title, authors (at most 2, otherwise with "et al"), year.

Comment: Imho a list of reference in a presentation is quite senseless. Also whatever you do it will waste a lot of space. Do you really want to do it? Why don't you create separate bibliography in a normal size that people can print out in a sensible way?

Comment: There is not one option that means "make it compact", but you have to use several options for omitting various kinds of info or extra names. Please tell us what options (in section 3.1) you already use!

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: I think of bibliography list in the case of presentations as an appendix. It is there as a supplementary material that is mostly important when it is put online.

Comment: @pst: With `biblatex` I tried the following package options: `style=numeric,isbn=false,url=false,doi=false,eprint=false`

Comment: I think you will have to provide more information on what you would like to see in the bibliography. Add a detailed description of what you would like to achieve and maybe an example.

Comment: Are you OK with using `biblatex`? What is the basic style you would like to go for: `numeric`-like, `authoryear`/`authortitle` like?

Comment: @moewe: see my edit

Comment: Just a comment on the benefit of such a compact bibliography: If it is intended to be the bibliography for the presentation if put up online I think a full bibliography that allows the reader to locate the sources properly (journals for articles, etc. pp.) is more beneficial. Plus in such a context, space is not of utmost importance.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Another `biblatex` solution.

As basis we take `biblatex`'s `numeric` with `maxnames=2`

```
\usepackage[style=numeric,maxnames=2]{biblatex}
```

We define our short bibliography driver `std` that prints only the author/editor, title and date

```
\DeclareBibliographyDriver{std}{%
  \usebibmacro{bibindex}%
  \usebibmacro{begentry}%
  \usebibmacro{author/editor+others/translator+others}%
  \setunit{\labelnamepunct}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{title}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{date}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{finentry}}
```

We then map all the entries to use this driver (I really hoped, there would be a shorter, more elegant way to do this, but I have yet to find it)

```
\DeclareBibliographyAlias{article}{std}
\DeclareBibliographyAlias{book}{std}
\DeclareBibliographyAlias{booklet}{std}
\DeclareBibliographyAlias{collection}{std}
\DeclareBibliographyAlias{inbook}{std}
\DeclareBibliographyAlias{incollection}{std}
\DeclareBibliographyAlias{inproceedings}{std}
\DeclareBibliographyAlias{manual}{std}
\DeclareBibliographyAlias{misc}{std}
\DeclareBibliographyAlias{online}{std}
\DeclareBibliographyAlias{patent}{std}
\DeclareBibliographyAlias{periodical}{std}
\DeclareBibliographyAlias{proceedings}{std}
\DeclareBibliographyAlias{report}{std}
\DeclareBibliographyAlias{thesis}{std}
\DeclareBibliographyAlias{unpublished}{std}
\DeclareBibliographyAlias{*}{std}
```

To get the citation label instead of the "cute little icon", we can use

```
\setbeamertemplate{bibliography item}[text]
```

See *Beamer-Template/-Color/-Font `bibliography item`*, p. 102 of [the `beamer` user guide](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/beamer/doc/beameruserguide.pdf).

MWE

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[style=numeric,maxnames=2]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\setbeamertemplate{bibliography item}[text]

\DeclareBibliographyAlias{article}{std}
\DeclareBibliographyAlias{book}{std}
\DeclareBibliographyAlias{booklet}{std}
\DeclareBibliographyAlias{collection}{std}
\DeclareBibliographyAlias{inbook}{std}
\DeclareBibliographyAlias{incollection}{std}
\DeclareBibliographyAlias{inproceedings}{std}
\DeclareBibliographyAlias{manual}{std}
\DeclareBibliographyAlias{misc}{std}
\DeclareBibliographyAlias{online}{std}
\DeclareBibliographyAlias{patent}{std}
\DeclareBibliographyAlias{periodical}{std}
\DeclareBibliographyAlias{proceedings}{std}
\DeclareBibliographyAlias{report}{std}
\DeclareBibliographyAlias{thesis}{std}
\DeclareBibliographyAlias{unpublished}{std}
\DeclareBibliographyAlias{*}{std}

\DeclareBibliographyDriver{std}{%
  \usebibmacro{bibindex}%
  \usebibmacro{begentry}%
  \usebibmacro{author/editor+others/translator+others}%
  \setunit{\labelnamepunct}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{title}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{date}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{finentry}}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \cite{wilde,baez/article,cicero,aksin,westfahl:space,westfahl:frontier,gaonkar,britannica}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
  \printbibliography
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Of course you could also use `firstinits=true` to make the names even shorter.

Comment: We could further shorten the entries in some cases by using `\printtext[title]{\printfield[titlecase]{title}}` instead of `\usebibmacro{title}` that will also print the `subtitle` and `titleaddon` fields (of course, we could also use an `\AtEverybibitem{\clearfield{subtitle}\clearfield{titleaddon}}` approach). Also replacing `\usebibmacro{date}` with `\printfield{year}` suppresses `day` and `month` if available (again a `\AtEverybibitem{\clearfield{day}\clearfield{month}}` does not seem unreasonable here).

Comment: Is there a way to replace the (useless) symbol with the key generated by biblatex (that is the one that is typesetted as the output of `cite{F00}` in the body)?

Comment: @Dror Certainly, `\setbeamertemplate{bibliography item}[text]` should do that. See *Beamer-Template/-Color/-Font `bibliography item`*, p. 102 of [the `beamer` user guide](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/beamer/doc/beameruserguide.pdf). The usual caveats with presentations and bibliographies are mentioned there as well: The audience will probably not be able to remember the labels.

Comment: Setting the `bibliography item` to `text` helps, but only if the style in use is either `numeric` or `alphabetic`. What's the way to make it play with `authoryear`?

Comment: @Dror When I tested it with `authoryear`, I found the output was what I expected. If you use `authoryear` in a "normal" document you do not get the "label" printed before the actual entry either (it would be somewhat redundant to do that).

Comment: @Dror You could hack something like `\defbibenvironment{bibliography}{\list{\printtext[brackets]{\cite{\thefield{entrykey}}}}{\setlength{\leftmargin}{1cm}\setlength{\itemsep}{\bibitemsep}\setlength{\parsep}{\bibparsep}}}{\endlist}{\item}` together, but I doubt that this is useful.

Comment: @Dror You have to keep in mind that `authoryear` labels might get quite long (even in our case at hand a label might easily take up 1/4 of the slide width [take "Baez and Lauda 2004", I dread to think what "Westfahl and Westfahl 2012" would look like]), it seems unreasonable to expect an output similar to `numeric` or `alphabetic` where the labels are much shorter: there would be not enough space for the rest of the entry (that would contain redundant information now) and the whole thing will end up looking ridiculous.

Comment: good point! thnx!

Answer (score 10):

In the following, I use `biblatex` to:

- Restrict the number of author names to two by passing the `maxnames=2, minnames=2` options to the `biblatex` package.
- Tailor the content of the bibliography via the `\AtEveryitem` hook. Inside this hook, I use `\clearfield/name/list{<element>}` to exclude certain fields from being printed.

For many fields the latter is also possible by global `biblatex` options, such as `doi=false`. However, this does not work for all fields. For me, the hooks makes it also more easy to "play" with different settings by just commenting in/out the respective `\clearfield` lines.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage[backend=bibtex,style=numeric,maxnames=2, minnames=2]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{beamer.bib}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\begin{filecontents}{beamer.bib}
@article{hoare:69:cacm,
  author = {Hoare, C. A. R.},
  title = {An axiomatic basis for computer programming},
  journal = {Communications of the ACM},
  volume = 12,
  number = 10,
  month = oct,
  year = 1969,
  issn = {0001-0782},
  pages = {576--580},
  doi = {10.1145/363235.363259},
  publisher = {ACM Press},
  address = {New York, NY, USA},
}
@article{dijkstra:68:cacm,
  author = {Edsger Wybe Dijkstra},
  title = {The Structure of the {THE}-Multiprogramming System},
  journal = {Communications of the ACM},
  year = {1968},
  month = may,
  volume = 11,
  number = 5,
  pages = {341--346},
}
@article{graham:68:cacm,
  author = {Robert M. Graham},
  title = {Protection in an Information Processing Utility},
  journal = {Communications of the ACM},
  volume = {11},
  number = {5},
  month = may,
  year = {1968},
  issn = {0001-0782},
  pages = {365--369},
  doi = {10.1145/363095.363146},
  publisher = {ACM Press},
  address = {New York, NY, USA},
}
@inproceedings{henkel:11:codesisss,
  title = {Design and Architectures for Dependable Embedded Systems},
  author = { Henkel,J{\"o}rg and Bauer,Lars and Becker,Joachim and Bringmann,Oliver and Brinkschulte,Uwe and Chakraborty,Samarjit and Engel,Michael and Ernst,Rolf and H{\"a}rtig,Hermann and Hedrich,Lars and Herkersdorf,Andreas and R{\"u}diger Kapitza and Daniel Lohmann and Marwedel,Peter and Platzner,Marco and Rosenstiel,Wolfgang and Schlichtmann,Ulf and Spinczyk,Olaf and Tahoori,Mehdi and J{\"u}rgen Teich and Wehn,Norbert and Wunderlich,Hans-Joachim},
  keywords = {embedded systems, dependable systems, danceos},
  doi = {10.1145/2039370.2039384},
  pages = {69--78},
  editor = {Robert P. Dick and Jan Madsen},
  isbn = {978-1-4503-0715-4},
  venue = {Taipei, Taiwan},
  booktitle = {Proceedings of the 9th IEEE/ACM International Conference on Hardware/Software Codesign and System Synthesis (CODES+ISSS '11)},
  year = {2011},
  month = oct,
  publisher = {ACM Press},
}

\end{filecontents}


% Content Tailoring
%
% tailor content of bibliography
\AtEveryBibitem{
   \clearfield{month}
   \clearfield{series}
   \clearfield{venue}
   \clearname{editor}
   \clearlist{publisher}
   \clearlist{location} % alias to field 'address'
   \clearfield{doi}
   \clearfield{url}
   \clearfield{venue}
   \clearfield{issn}
   \clearfield{isbn}
   \clearfield{urldate}
   \clearfield{eventdate}
   %\clearfield{pages}
   %\clearfield{booktitle}
   %\clearfield{journaltitle}
   %\clearfield{number}
   %\clearfield{volume}
}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]
    \printbibliography
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

The result looks as follows:

[image]

If you want to get rid of even more data, just uncomment the additional lines in the `\AtEveryBibitem` handler:

[image]

Comment: Further space reduction is possible by changing the font, the layout of the bibliography (for instance the indentation of the entries) and so on. However, I don't know if that is an option for you.

Comment: Is there a specific reason for using `bibtex` as the backend?

Comment: Do you know why sometimes it is `In: 2011` and sometimes `In: (1969)`?

Comment: @Dror This is due to the fact that `@article`s have the `date` wrapped in parentheses, while `@inbook`s/`@incollection` and the like get the date printed without parentheses. (Have a look at the normal output of `style=numeric` without the modifications) The "In:" stems from using the standard drivers that will print `\usebibmacro{in:}`. You could suppress it via `\renewbibmacro{in:}{}`.

Comment: @Dror: There is no specific need for `bibtex` as backend. I just used it because `biber` is not yet installed on my machine. Regarding the brackets, the 'In:' and so on: The good thing with `biblatex` is that all this can relatively easily be changed (see @moewe's comment). A detailed specification would be good, though.

Comment: `In: 1981` etc. seems a little odd -- is there an easy way to drop the "In: "for your 2nd example?

Comment: @ChrisH: This is a question of the chosen bibliography style, but sure: Just add `\renewbibmacro{in:}{}` to your preamble and it will disappear.

Comment: N.B.: `\clearfield{eventdate}` does not work in current versions of biblatex (styles building on standard.bbx). It may be necessary to do something like `\renewbibmacro*{event+venue+date}{\newunit}`.

Answer (score 5):

With this style file:
http://comedy.dante.de/~herbert/Bibliography/plain-short.bst

and

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\bibliographystyle{plain-short}
\bibliography{ref-antibiotics}

\end{document}
```

you'll get:

[image]

Comment: This yields just as long output as `plain`... Actually, a bit longer as it includes the ISBN :(

Comment: What fields do you want to see?

Comment: See my edit above

Comment: I edited my answer and updated the bst file

Comment: Indeed better. One of the problems I had was that apparently the order of the keys in the entry matters! I did not know it.

Comment: next try ... ;-)

Comment: the link is dead

Comment: Link edited ...

Answer (score 4):

For shortening bibliographies I recommend to generate a new bib file, where you specify only the fields you really need. (Leaving out middle names, employ common conference and journal abbreviations, etc.) 
As you see in the answer from Daniel, it is not easy to filter them out afterwards, and you will probably miss one or two.
Keep in mind, that some bibitems e.g. `@article` need some journal title and will print extra symbols like: `In:`. For that, Moewe greatly smashes all bibitems to some std type, very elegantly!

So now to my contribution: Ahh there is none, just searched this site for some time.

- Basically, there is much space wasted from item symbols to item text (horizontally). You may reduce this with: `\setlength{\biblabelsep}{-0.5cm}`.
- Additionally, biblatex offers you the possibility to use for the firstnames initials as well: `firstinits=true`.
- the original symbol here, consumes a lot of space as well, change it to some smaller: `\setbeamertemplate{bibliography item}[triangle]`
- The rest comes from another great answer [Reduce spacing in bibliography using biblatex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17360/reduce-spacing-in-bibliography-using-biblatex/17363#17363), which I would consider a bit of a possible duplicate, however, your question is beamer related, so, the `begingroup` and `endgroup` stuff reduces vertical space once more:
- last but not least sometimes the microtype package might safe some space as well (this is one of the package I regular include)

```
\documentclass[compress]{beamer}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[style=numeric-comp,firstinits=true,maxcitenames=2,maxbibnames=2]{biblatex}
% % Do this to reduce size
% \renewcommand*{\bibfont}{\footnotesize}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\DeclareBibliographyAlias{article}{std}
\DeclareBibliographyAlias{book}{std}
\DeclareBibliographyAlias{booklet}{std}
\DeclareBibliographyAlias{collection}{std}
\DeclareBibliographyAlias{inbook}{std}
\DeclareBibliographyAlias{incollection}{std}
\DeclareBibliographyAlias{inproceedings}{std}
\DeclareBibliographyAlias{manual}{std}
\DeclareBibliographyAlias{misc}{std}
\DeclareBibliographyAlias{online}{std}
\DeclareBibliographyAlias{patent}{std}
\DeclareBibliographyAlias{periodical}{std}
\DeclareBibliographyAlias{proceedings}{std}
\DeclareBibliographyAlias{report}{std}
\DeclareBibliographyAlias{thesis}{std}
\DeclareBibliographyAlias{unpublished}{std}
\DeclareBibliographyAlias{*}{std}

\DeclareBibliographyDriver{std}{%
  \usebibmacro{bibindex}%
  \usebibmacro{begentry}%
  \usebibmacro{author/editor+others/translator+others}%
  \setunit{\labelnamepunct}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{title}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{date}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{finentry}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[t,allowframebreaks]{Bibliography}
  \nocite{*}
  \begingroup
  \setstretch{0.8}
  \linespread{0.9}
  \setbeamertemplate{bibliography item}[triangle]
  \setlength\bibitemsep{-0pt}
  \setlength{\biblabelsep}{-0.5cm}
  \printbibliography
  \endgroup
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

in comparison to moewes answer:
 [image]

Comment: There is really no point in `\clear`ing all those fields if one then uses the `std` driver as above, they will not be printed anyway. Note that `\clearname{editor}` can actually have an adverse effect as can be seen with the "Alternative Modernities"  entry (bibkey: `gaonkar` in `biblatex-examples.bib`). Also note that the option to use first name initials is called `firstinits=true` and not `firstinitials=true` (your MWE uses the right code, your explanation doesn't though).

Comment: Thanks, I removed the `\clear`-stuff

Comment: What's the difference between your answer and @moewe's?

Comment: Its about spacing, hence mine is more compact. Look in the list I gave in my answer. As before you use spacing, unneccessary content should be removed, hence I used moewes approach for that.

Comment: I provided a direct visual comparison to moewes answer.

Comment: Thanks. Nice additional tweaks. Somehow the `\setlength{\biblabelsep}{-0.5cm}` doesn't work for me... The text comes on top of the marker.

Comment: Maybe you can specify a smaller length. BTW: the more I read my answer, the less I am convinced that this is right approach in tweaking space for references. The more tinier you make them the harder they become to read. Whenever I notice interesting references in a talk I note down: year an first author. This usually suffices. So my current practice is just also to put a note like thie [Foobar, 2009] beneath a picture or other referrencial work. As when the talk or presentation is over, nobody will care about references anymore. If the talk is a lecture, than it might be worth, listing the ref