# Single line bibliography in bibunit

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, bibunits

I would like to shrink to a single line or a single paragraph my bibliography once I print it by `\putbib[<mybibfile>]` within a section using [`bibunit`](http://mirrors.ircam.fr/pub/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/bibunits/bibunits.pdf) package. A [related post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5571/reduce-bibliography-to-one-line) suggests a potential way yet for a global bilbiography environment. And in fact adding the `\renewenvironment{thebibliography}` as suggested in that post before loading `natbib` and `bibunit` does not have any effect in my case. If I do it after `natbib` or `bibunit` the compilation halts with several errors. Any suggestions? I specify that I am using `BibTeX` and compiling either with `PDFLateX` or 'XeLateX` insofar as unfortunately, this is a preset class for a job application that I cannot modify.

In particular my setup looks right now as following:

```
\documentclass{<my_doc_class>} %my_doc_class is a child of 'article'
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[francais,english]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc} %% For ISO-latin1 chars (accented letters).
\usepackage{txfonts} % Use Times, Helvetica fonts

\usepackage{graphicx} % For the Inria logo and other figures
\parindent 0pt
\usepackage[cm]{fullpage} % Use the entire page (1.5 cm margins everywhere)

%-----------------------
% GENERAL SETTINGS
%-----------------------
\usepackage{paralist}
\usepackage{enumitem}

%-----------------------
% BIBLIOGRAPHY
%-----------------------
\renewenvironment{thebibliography}[1]{%
   \section*{\refname}\inparaenum[{[}1{]}]}{\endinparaenum}
\renewcommand{\bibitem}[1]{\item}

\usepackage[numbers,super,sort,compress]{natbib}
\usepackage[subsectionbib]{bibunits}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{doi}

\begin{document}
\bibliographyunit[\section]
\defaultbibliographystyle{naturemag_doi}

...
...

\section{Contribution~1}
\vspace{1em}
\subsection{\BiLingual{Description de la contribution}{ / }{Description of the contribution}}

<some text with several \citep{...} commands>
...
...

\putbib[mybib_file]

\section{Contribution~2}

<some text with several \citep{...} commands>
...
...
\putbib[mybib_file]

...
...
\end{document}
```

Each command `\putbib` will print the "Bibliography" per each section as:

```
[1] Ref. 1

[2] Ref. 2

[3] Ref. 3
...
...
```

Instead what I would like, due to the space limitations of the document I am working with, is to have each Bibliography as

```
[1] Ref. 1 [2] Ref. 2 [3] Ref. 3 ...
```

The `naturemag_doi` bst file is some custom bibliography style that I preliminarly compiled by `makebst`. It is not crucial here. You can consider and other standard natbib style like `apalike` if it ease to work out a solution.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Could you show us your set-up in more detail in an [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864)? That will allow us to assess your situation more easily and accurately. Maybe you could also give more details about the expected outcome with a 'mock-up' of what you'd like to see.

Comment: Sure Let me edit a bit my question. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, after a while, I ultimately figured out that `biblatex` is better to handle this case. So in the preamble, I declared:

```
\usepackage[backend=bibtex,
            maxnames = 3,
            firstinits=false,
            uniquename=init,
            autocite=superscript,
            style=nature,
            articletitle=false,
            natbib=true]{biblatex}
% Add BIB files            
\addbibresource{my_publications.bib}
\addbibresource{my_resstat.bib}

% Define environment for single-line bibliography in the subsection
\defbibenvironment{oneline}
{}
{}
{\addspace
 \printtext[labelnumberwidth]{%
   \printfield{prefixnumber}%
   \printfield{labelnumber}}%
 \addhighpenspace}
```

This will automatically make the bibliography in each section/subsection lumped in a single line or paragraph. It is not, properly speaking, the answer to my original question, but rather a workaround. Nevertheless, the reason I ultimately switched to `biblatex` in this case is because I needed to do several fine tunings on my bibliography, in addition to this one posted here, and as excellently explained [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25701/bibtex-vs-biber-and-biblatex-vs-natbib), and in the [`biblatex` manual](http://ctan.mines-albi.fr/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf), the advantages bore by `biblatex` over `natbib` in customizing bibliographies are worth to spend an initial additional time to figure out how to make it work.

Comment: See also [What is the easiest way to generate a compact bibliography?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/169306/35864), [Compressed / abbreviated bibliography? (Biblatex or otherwise?)](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/124513/35864), [Removing Line Breaks in Bibliography compiled with Biblatex](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/140787/35864)