# biblatex and koma reduntant space around bibliography

Tags: biblatex, koma-script

I'm trying to create a CV based on tabular environments with the date in the left column and the information in the right. I want to add my publications in the same way: some 'category' in the left column, the citation in the right. To create the categories (like book chapter, paper, in preparation etc.), I used `biblatex` with bibfilters. In the Publications section, I suppress the `section` and set it manually into the left column.

It almost works, but there's some extra space below and above the Publications blocks that I'd like to get rid off. The goal is that it looks exactly like the other entries, if possible without manually tweaking negative `vspace`s. I'm guessing that some of the space above might belong to the suppressed `section`, but not sure.

I found this question: [Reduce spacing in bibliography using biblatex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17360/reduce-spacing-in-bibliography-using-biblatex#17363), but it only addresses the space between bibliography items.

Here's my code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 10pt, parskip=half]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[left = 3.0cm, top = 2.0cm, right = 2.0cm, bottom = 2.0cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[dvipsnames, table]{xcolor}

\usepackage[sorting = none, bibstyle = authoryear, backend = biber]{biblatex} %
\addbibresource{Publications.bib}
\DeclareBibliographyCategory{a}
\DeclareBibliographyCategory{b}
\addtocategory{a}{Whiskey2016}
\addtocategory{a}{Whiskey2015}
\addtocategory{b}{Whiskey2015}
\defbibfilter{a}{category=a}
\defbibfilter{b}{category=b}

\usepackage[tracking=true]{microtype}

\newcommand\titlerule[1][1pt]{\rule{\linewidth}{#1}}
\renewcommand*{\sectionformat}{%
    \rlap{\parbox[t][8\height][b]{\textwidth}{\titlerule}}}
\setkomafont{section}{\mdseries\scshape\lsstyle\Large}

\newcommand{\cvd}[2]{#1\ifthenelse{\equal{#2}{}}{}{\newline{-- #2}}}

\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\raggedleft\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}


\begin{document}    
\section{Education}
\begin{tabular}{R{2cm}|L{13cm}}
    \cvd{Feb/2013}{present} & studied somewhere else\newline%
    \emph{some very very long department name, and even longer and very stupid university name}, town, country\\
    \multicolumn{2}{c}{}\\
    \cvd{Feb/2010}{Jan/2012} & studied somewhere\newline%
    \emph{Department, University}, town, country\\
\end{tabular}

\section{Publications}
\begingroup
\renewcommand{\section}[2]{}
\nocite{Whiskey2016}
\nocite{Whiskey2015}
\begin{tabular}{R{2cm}|L{13cm}}
    {\mdseries\scshape\small Peer-reviewed} & \printbibliography[filter = a]\\
    \multicolumn{2}{c}{}\\
    {\mdseries\scshape\small Other (in~print)} & \printbibliography[filter = b]\\
\end{tabular}
\endgroup
\end{document}
```

And the contents of the .bib file:

```
@Article{Whiskey2016,
  author  = {Johnnie Walker and Jim Beam and Jack Daniels},
  title   = {How to taste whiskey},
  journal = {The whiskey tasting journal},
  year    = {2016},
}

@Article{Whiskey2015,
  author  = {Johnnie Walker and Jim Beam and Jack Daniels},
  title   = {How to taste even more whiskey},
  journal = {The whiskey tasting journal},
  year    = {2015},
}
```

And an image of the output:
[image: reduntant space around bibliography]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could define a new bibliography heading and a new bibliography environment

```
\defbibheading{nobibheading}{}
\defbibenvironment{cvdbibliography}
  {\begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth}
    \list{}{%
      \setlength\itemsep{0pt}%
      \setlength\parsep{0pt}%
      \setlength{\leftmargin}{\bibhang}%
      \setlength{\itemindent}{-\leftmargin}%
    }%
  }
  {\strut\endlist\end{minipage}}
  {\item}
```

and then

```
\begin{tabular}{>{\mdseries\scshape\small}R{2cm}|L{13cm}}
    Peer-reviewed 
      & \printbibliography[filter = a,heading=nobibheading,env=cvdbibliography]\\
    \multicolumn{2}{c}{}\\
    Other (in~print) 
      & \printbibliography[filter = b,heading=nobibheading,env=cvdbibliography]\\
\end{tabular}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, your solution worked, except for one tiny change:

My actual code also used the `hyperref` package to link the doi's of the papers, but I did not include it in the MWE.

With your custom bibliography environment and `hyperref`, there were still some vertical spaces. center- or bottom-aligning the `minipage` solved it (instead of top-aligning as in your code):
`\begin{minipage}[c]{\linewidth}`
even though I do not have any clue why ...